# Literally a million files on Temporary Internet Files folder. OrganizationUsers.xml - What is this?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I literally have just short of a million files in my Temporary Internet Files folder.  A large amount of them show an Internet Address of http://127.0.0.1:43958/Admin/XML/OrganizationUsers.xml?ID=6856&sync=x where x is an ever changing number.

There are also a large number of similarly named files; http://127.0.0.1:43958/Admin/XML/Gateways.xml?ID=&sync=x where x is an ever changing number.

I Googled "OrganizationUsers.xml" and "Gateways.xml" and got no hits.  Does anyone know what these files are and why they're on my server?  I'm running Windows Server 2012R2.

Comment: What's installed on the server? Exchange Server by any chance? Skype/Lync? Something else? Those look like temp files for an application or server product.

Comment: No Exchange Server.  All it's doing is hosting a couple websites, so just IIS8, I've got Visual Studio since I'm doing everything in C#.  I'm not really a server guy, I know enough to get some bare bones stuff running, I wasn't sure if anyone would recognize them as anything ominous.

Comment: I would suspect VS as the culprit.